# Nginx removing second slash in location block

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set up nginx with `proxy_pass` when a unique URL is visited:

```
location ~ /proxy/(?<var>.+) {
    proxy_pass $var;
}
```

When I visit `http://example.com/proxy/http://google.com` I get a 500 Internal Server Error, and the error log has the below entry:

> invalid URL prefix in "http:/google.com", client: 2.33.214.165,
>   server: example.com, request: "GET /proxy/http://google.com HTTP/1.1",
>   host: "example.com"

Is there any reason why nginx doesn't include the second `/` in the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this: [merge_slashes](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes)
though the context is server wide, so if you still need to merge slashes elsewhere you will have to improve your regexp in the location splitting the proxy target into schema and host+uri. something like this:`^/proxy/(?<schema>.+)://(?<rest>)` and then `proxy_pass $schema://$rest` may work.